# WinForms Application Theme

Tags: .net, winforms, custom-controls

Is there any way to change the SystemColors.ButtonHighlight color only for my WinForms application? I would like to give a different theme to it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be nice, wouldn't it?

I'm afraid the only options are to draw the button yourself (use Reflector to see how WinForms paints it), or buy a third-party skinning framework.

Comment: Wow, it would require subclassing each single WinForms control, override the OnPaint() and replace the function body with something copied from Reflector?

Comment: You won't be able to copy from Reflector as the drawing code is very complex (using adapters for various button types, etc.). The idea is just to see how it works for the simple case. And yes, you have to replace all occurances of Button with MyButton in your project. A skinning framework is a better solution as they've already done all the heavy lifting.

Answer (score 2):

[DotNetSkin](http://www.dotnetskin.net/) provides a DLL which can be easily used in an application to change full theme including the title bar of the application that would not depend upon Windows theme.

Many themes are available there or you can create your own theme or use any `.msStyle` file in your application.

Comment: I know we can purchase a skinning tool, but we need to provide a solution without any third party component.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd have to make a custom control that inherits a button, then override the OnPaint event and draw the ButtonHighlight (and probably the rest of the button as well) yourself.

Comment: I camped on this page for too long and didn't see that someone else gave the same answer, sorry. However, I've had a great experience using the DotNetBar controls which have skinning ability.