# How to change selected menustrip item color?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I have changed the menu strip item to from the default color to a new color. However, when selected, it goes to the default color. What property do I have to change so that I can seem a DimGray background when I click the tool strip item?

I've tried the click instance of the item to change the BackColor to Color.Dimgray, but that didn't work. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: changing colors that way always runs the risk of your choice not working well with the users selected color scheme.

Comment: Agreed, but you sometimes have to do as your told for color schemes from the Powers That Be. :D

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4087769/1070452

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - when the user selects the `ToolStripMenuItem`, the dropdown menu is then shown, the `MenuItem` has changed back to the original colour.

This can be solved by creating a sub which handles the dropdown opened event for the `MenuItem` by changing the item's forecolor and/or backcolor, for example:

```vb
Private Sub ToolStripMenuItem2_DropDownOpened(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ToolStripMenuItem2.DropDownOpened
    ToolStripMenuItem2.ForeColor = Color.Black
End Sub
```